# Java RB Tree deletion

Tags: java

i am trying to implement RB Tree alghoritm from T. H. Cormen, and can't find solution for my problem. There is a NullPinterException, when i want to delete some nodes. Here is my code:

```
        public void rbTreeDelete(RBNode z) {
        RBNode y = z;
        RBNode x = new RBNode();
        Color yOriginalColor = y.color;
        if(z.left == null) {
            x = z.right;
            rbTransplant(z, z.right);
        }
        else {
            if(z.right == null) {
                x = z.left;
                rbTransplant(z, z.left);
            }

            else {
                y = treeMinimum(z.right);
                yOriginalColor = y.color;
                x = y.right;
                if(y.p == z) {
                    x.p = y;
                }
                else {
                    rbTransplant(y, y.right);
                    y.right = z.right;
                    y.right.p = y;
                }
                rbTransplant(z, y);
                y.left = z.left;
                y.left.p = y;
                y.color = z.color;
            }
            if(yOriginalColor == Color.Black) {
                rbDeleteFixup(x);
            }
        }
    }
    public void rbTransplant(RBNode u,RBNode v) {
        if(u.p == null) {
            root = v;
        }
        else {
            if(u == u.p.left){
                u.p.left = v;
            }
            else {
                u.p.right = v;
            }
        }
        if (v != null) {
            v.p = u.p;
        }
    }
    public void rbDeleteFixup(RBNode x){
        while(x !=root && x.color == Color.Black) {
            if(x == x.p.left) {
                RBNode w;
                w = x.p.right;
                if(w.color == Color.Red) {
                    w.color = Color.Black;
                    x.p.color = Color.Red;
                    leftRotate(x.p);
                    w = x.p.right;
                }
                if(w.left.color == Color.Black && w.right.color == Color.Black) {
                    w.color = Color.Red;
                    x = x.p;
                }
                else {
                    if(w.right.color == Color.Black) {
                        w.left.color = Color.Black;
                        w.color = Color.Red;
                        rightRotate(w);
                        w = x.p.right;
                    }
                    w.color = x.p.color;
                    x.p.color = Color.Black;
                    w.right.color = Color.Black;
                    leftRotate(x.p);
                    x = root;
                }
            }
            else {
                RBNode w = x.p.left;
                if(w.color == Color.Red) {
                    w.color = Color.Black;
                    x.p.color = Color.Red;
                    rightRotate(x.p);
                    w = x.p.left;
                }
                if(w.right.color == Color.Black && w.left.color == Color.Black) {
                    w.color = Color.Red;
                    x = x.p;
                }
                else {
                    if(w.left.color == Color.Black) {
                        w.right.color = Color.Black;
                        w.color = Color.Red;
                        rightRotate(w);
                        w = x.p.left;
                    }
                    w.color = x.p.color;
                    x.p.color = Color.Black;
                    w.left.color = Color.Black;
                    leftRotate(x.p);
                    x = root;
                }
            }
        }
        x.color = Color.Black;
    }
```

Exception is in the line:

> ```
>             if(y.p == z) {
>                 x.p = y;
>             }
> ```
>
> in rbTreeDelete method, when i try to delete node with 9 value. My test script:

```
                t.insert(7);
            t.insert(5);
            t.insert(8);
            t.insert(3);
            t.insert(9);
            t.insert(18);
            t.insert(32);
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 32));
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 9));
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 8));
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 5));
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 8));
            t.rbTreeDelete(treeSearch(t.root, 3));
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: treeMinimum code:

```
        public RBNode treeMinimum(RBNode x) {
        while(x.left != null){
            x = x.left;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: can you supply the code for treeMinimum, since this is supplying y.

Comment: sure, i added it to first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the problem lies in the below code:

Here you set "y" to the tree Minimum from the right of z (since z.right != null), this is good.

However, this minimum value does not guarantee that y will have a right node (y.right != null)

I believe you could be receiving a null pointer due to x being set to null, before attempting to assign a parent node value.

```
else {
                y = treeMinimum(z.right);
                yOriginalColor = y.color;
                x = y.right;
                if(y.p == z) {
                    x.p = y;
                }
```

Comment: y.right is null, so x is set to null too, but i declared it before as a node and i think it should be possible to set it parent x.p. But it's not...

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Although x has been initiated as a Node, once set to null the memory location is cleared, so it will no longer act as a Node Object